# Корректно убрать поля при выборе метода доставки в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня на сайте три вида доставки (СДЭК, Почта России и самовывоз). Для каждого свои поля, обязательные для заполнения (ФИО, адрес, индекс, телефон и т.д.). Я хочу для Самовывоза убрать лишние поля. Делаю это следующим кодом:

```
/* убираем поля для разных видов доставки:*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_checkout_fields' );
function override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 
   // получаем выбранные метод доставки
   $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
   
   // проверяем текущий метод и убираем нененужные поля
   //if ( 'free_shipping:1' === $chosen_methods[0] ) {
   if ( 'local_pickup:3' === $chosen_methods[0]) { // Самовывоз 
    
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1_field']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
 
   }
   
   return $fields;
}
```

Но возникает проблема - браузер кэширует страницу. Получается если я выбрал "Самовывоз", то приведенный код работает - лишние поля убираются, но если после этого выбрать "СДЭК", то убранные поля не возвращаются (или возвращаются криво, например, без лэйблов). При очистке кэша в браузере поля отображаются правильно.

За поля других двух видов доставки отвечают соответствующие плагины, которые корректно убирают ненужные поля и добавляют "нужные". То есть как-то можно регулировать корректное появление/удаление этих полей.

Вопрос - как принудительно НЕкэшировать страницу или удалять-добавлять поля, чтобы они не кэшировались?

Comment: Браузер не может кешировать аякс-запросы.

Comment: То есть когда я меняю доставку и поля начинают некорректно работать - это конфликт плагина СДЭК с моим кодом идет, да?

Answer (score 1):

Не должно там кешироваться. Там вызов [WC_AJAX::update_shipping_method](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_ajaxupdate_shipping_method/) идет при изменение способа доставки

Метод возвращает self::get_cart_totals(); - - т.е. стоимость итоговую

Нужно либо подцепить на изменение доставки - обновление полей через ajax, либо перегружать страницу

Comment: Ну это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: слишком мало информации, чтоб дать точный ответ. у задавшего вопрос есть заблуждение по кешированию результата смена типы доставки. но смена доставки возвращает лишь итоговую сумму по корзине.

Comment: значит нужно спросить об этом в комментарии или попробовать закрыть вопрос)